# Laravel - Third Party Packages interfering in Migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5

After searching a lot I came here. I am a newbie to laravel. From last 2 hours I am stuck on a bug. One of the third party package `Thujohn/Twitter` is interfering in my migrations. I had done migrations several times before. But due to some reasons I decided to rollback my migration and I got error,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Thujohn\Twitter\Facades\Twitter::down() in my/project/root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php on line 199
```

I have no idea what this error is. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the method (function) isn't found. I guess the whole package isn't installed. Maybe you could try again.

Have you installed the package as the README file in GitHub says?

https://github.com/Thujohn/Twitter

Comment: I think so that question is not clear to you. This library is interfering in my migrations. I have installed it correctly

Comment: Could you try to remove the package, then migrate and then install it again?